# Angular calling springboot backend not working

Tags: java, angular, rest, api

I have the following setup:
Angular method:

```
assignPrivilegesToRole(id: number, privlist: Privilege[]): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrlPriv}/assignprivs/${id}/${privlist}`);
  }
```

Springboot:

```
@GetMapping("/privileges/assignprivs/{id}/{privlist}")
    public boolean assignPrivilegesToRole(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long roleId,
            @PathVariable(value = "privlist") List<Privilege> privList) {
       //testing purpose
        return true;
    }
```

In this setup angular cannot reach spring boot. If I make the same setup but only with the Id parameter, it reaches backend.
Any suggestion on how can I send an Id and a list of objects to backend?
Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: can you share  example request generated from angular?

Comment: Use post request and pass list data through body

Comment: Vinay, I would but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

SB code is fine.

You must check your request, to me it looks like the issue is `privlist: Privilege[]`. This must append a string with `[` and `]` brace causing request to fail.

Your request should be like below:

> localhost:8080/pathVarTest/ed/test,rest

i.e. comma separated  with no braces on list type path variable.

> Ideally you should make a POST call in this case and pass the list as POST body.

Comment: he is using custom Privilege object list then how it going to work, it will works if he has String or integer List of array

Comment: OP must send the request in desired format on backend in this case. Backend endpoint is fine the issue is in the request creation at front-end. From best practices perspective opinions will surely differ .

Comment: And how could I make it work? I think I fried my brain trying to solve this.

Comment: can you share your request ? Because I can help once I see your request. Ideally you should make a POST call in this case and pass the list as POST body.

Comment: I don't know where to find the request. I'd like to try it with POST but have no idea on how to pass it in the body

Comment: @AndreiMîndru SO don't work that way man. You have to put your efforts and then if you are not able to you can place question for same on SO.